# Errors while syncing iPhone

Tags: data-synchronization, iphone

I did a restore on my iPhone 3GS running the latest 4.2.1 (after a failed attempt at jailbreaking).

For whatever reason the applications won't sync. For each of the apps it gives me an error:

The app "iDivide" was not installed on the iPhone "iPhone" because an unknown error occured (0xE8000001).

I've shutdown and restarted the phone, all to no avail.  Everything else seems to sync fine (photos, podcasts, etc...).

How do I sync my apps?

Comment: Did you restore from DFU to the stock firmware or from some sub-state that the jailbreaking process placed you in?

Comment: I connected the iPhone to iTunes, clicked Restore and it did its things from there.

Comment: @AngryHacker - I am facing this now - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213205/restore-from-backup-causes-message-apps-in-your-itunes-library-were-not-install Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This restore that you did, was it from a backup made pre-jailbreak or post-jailbreak? It may not matter but it always helps to isolate possible sources of errors.

I know these are a bit of a generic set of tests, but have you tried:

- Deleting and re-downloading a couple of apps to test if the app files have been corrupted?
- Reinstalling iTunes, to test if the iTunes installation has been corrupted?
- Set up the phone "as a new phone", to test if the backup is what is causing the sync error? If this doesn't work you can still go back to restoring from backup.

If none of those help, the more drastic options are:

- Delete and re-download the IPSW file and re-restore the phone with the fresh IPSW, to test if the IPSW file on your computer has been corrupted.
- Copy your iTunes Library to another computer, to test if iTunes + your computer is having problems (Reinstalling iTunes isn't quite as exact as a fresh install).
- Move your iTunes Library to a temporary location, start iTunes and let it create a blank Library, download a few apps to test, then see if it syncs.

Comment: I am facing this now - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213205/restore-from-backup-causes-message-apps-in-your-itunes-library-were-not-install Thoughts?

Comment: @AlexS It seems like you have an incomplete jailbreak (as evidenced by the WWDC app).  Is that the case?

Comment: @AngryHacker - Image is not of my screen. Its from another similar thread that I linked. I am able to install a lot of apps.. Close to 12/1300, around 2/300 dont make it. Total 1600 I think.

Answer (score 1):

Many resources out on the web seem to suggest that 0xE8000001 occurs because of iTunes/associated daemons, not your device itself. Most folks report success after quitting iTunes, and using Activity Monitor to force quit the iTunes Helper, and any other process referencing iTunes, iPod/iPhone, etc.

A blanket search for 0xE8000001 reveals most of these sources.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried all that (e.g. restarting iTunes, killing related processes, restarting computer) and nothing worked.

Comment: Well. Poop. (4 more to go..)

Answer (score 1):

VxJasonxV is correct about the error. Though normally the fault actually lies with Antivirus software on a Windows machine causing said daemon to fail.

Also: if a USB hub is being used, connect directly to the computer at try. The error is not consistent with that failure but it can cause problems.