# Restore from Backup: Apps in iTunes library were not installed on iPhone because Unknown Error occurred 0xE800002D

Tags: iphone, itunes, applications, data-synchronization, error

After iPhone **Restore from Backup & Sync** causes **iTunes Error Message**:

I posted this weird copying behavior here:
[Issues & Errors with Restore from ios7 Backup to ios9 on iPhone 5?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212320/issues-errors-with-restore-from-ios7-backup-to-ios9-on-iphone-5)

---

The screenshot of error message below is from this [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5324051/) from Apple forums.

> [image]

---

I get a similar looking error message, but with 200+ errors (as posted with details below):

So I split & posted this **Error Message** separately to solve this issue.

> Some of the apps in your iTunes library were not installed on the iPhone “AS_iPhone5_711” because one or more errors occurred.
> For a list of apps that could not be installed, click the + below.
> ..
> The app “xxxx” was not installed on the iPhone “My_iPhone5_711” because an unknown **error occurred (0xE800002D)**.  // most apps have this error
> ..
> The app “yyyy” was not installed on the iPhone “My_iPhone5_711” because an unknown **error occurred (0xE800000E)**.  // few apps, maybe only one or bit more

---

A few 'tries' of **Restore from Backup & Sync**, I observed some of the following behaviors:

- Sync is stuck for several Apps that are in a "**funky**" state:

  - **On the iPhone: "Waiting" state**:
    Folders & Apps all pending, semi grayed icons. Some with names visible others names 'waiting..'. If you clicked one its name would become 'waiting..'
  - **On iTunes: Device > Apps view** they were all **"Will Install"** state:
    But every time I sync apps don't install & the same flavor of errors come up
- For one app, when I upgraded the version via iTunes and it synced/ installed finally, but the rest did not work despite updates.
- It does not consistently 'funk' the same Apps. Once it was Viber, next time it was WhatsApp (and a lot of other apps, but the apps kind of changed)
  PS: I thought maybe it was AppSync causing it so I got rid of it last 2 'tries'.
- Most of these are legit & free purchased from AppStore
- Computer was also authorized via iTunes

I don't mind taking manual steps to resolve this as long as there is some way.

---

Found some posts that talk about this error, but they are old and not sure if connected.

Jun 06, 2013: https://discussions.apple.com/message/22259435#22259435
2011 - 2013/14: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2765754?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been a pain since the move to iOS 9.

There is not ultimate fix for this, but these are things I've found that helped in various combinations and order. I will update this answer with additional workarounds whenever I come across them.

- Sometimes its stuck at this place:
  [iTunes 10.5 and IOS 5 sync hang at "Waiting for items to copy", possible fix](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3410559)
- At other times, this has helped:
  http://www.seriouslytrivial.com/2015/09/26/iphone-5-to-iphone-6s-upgrade-nightmare/
  http://www.seriouslytrivial.com/2015/09/30/fixing-iphone-apps-stuck-on-waiting/
- At times, while I was still connected to iTunes I'd go to AppStore and download the "Waiting" App from there, and other times that would not work.
- Certain times, the number of Waiting Apps/ Warnings would just slowly decrease each time I make iTunes sync with the phone.

  - A recent example was from 200 > 193 > 175 and so on..

There are some grave issues with Apple's iTunes Sync with iPhones and made even more grave with recent App Slicing and iCloud integration, we'll have to reply on Trial and Error some of the above on this.

And for a 64GB iPhone, given that neither the USB 2 speed connection or the WiFi speeds are good enough or fast enough to Backup and Restore the data (It took my iPhone 64 GB 12+ Hours to do a Restore from Backup and was still faulty), so when iPhone's can sync at USB 3 SuperSpeeds, we might have a better experience.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing those bugged apps direct from the App Store, as opposed to relying on the backup package.

Use the backup to get your own content (photos, messages, etc), and ignore the apps. Download them fresh from the app store.

Comment: Are you saying not to "restore from backup"? Or only those specific apps after the Restore? 

What if I have crucial data in some of those apps?

Comment: Restore from backup to get your unique content back onto the phone. Get as far as you can, I'm going to assume at least some of the apps will install correctly. If the crucial data is stored in iCloud, grabbing a new copy of the app from the app store should not affect it.